# Java - Multithreading - volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I wanted to do make a program that allows to `start x threads` and all threads are supposed to do a job:

> counting average from Math.random() when number > 0.

I started doing it without `volatile boolean` and it did not work.
But with volatile boolean it works as expected.

Could anyone explain me please why? Would it be possible to make it differently?

```
public class Worker extends Thread {

    private int number;
    private double average = 0;
    private volatile boolean cancelled;

    public Worker(int number) {
        this.number = number;
        cancelled = false;
    }

    public void run() {
            while (!cancelled) {
                if (number > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                        average += Math.random();
                        if (number - 1 == i) {
                            average = average/this.number;
                            number = 0;
                            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " average is: " + average);
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is cancelled...");
    }


    public void cancel() {
        this.cancelled = true;
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return this.average;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

}

    public class Executor {

    private List<Worker> activeThreads;
    private Double[] array;

    public Executor(){
        activeThreads = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void createThreads(int number, int count){
        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
            Worker worker = new Worker(count);
            worker.setName("Thread " + i);
            activeThreads.add(worker);
            array = new Double[number];
            worker.start();
        }
    }

    public void cancelThreads(){
        int count = 0;
        for(Worker w : activeThreads){
            w.cancel();
            try {
                  array[count] = w.getAverage();
                  count++;
                  w.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Interrupted exception");
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        getFinalAverage();
    }

    public void startJob(int num){
        activeThreads.forEach(t -> t.setNumber(num));
    }


    public void getActiveThreads(){
        System.out.println(Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().size());
    }

    private void getFinalAverage(){
        double finalAverage = 0;
        for(Double d : Arrays.asList(array)){
            finalAverage += d;
        }
        finalAverage = finalAverage / array.length;
        System.out.println("Final average is " + finalAverage);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to share mutable state between threads in Java, you need some sort of thread synchronization, `volatile` fields being one of the options. Without that, there are no guarantees that threads can read data written by other threads timely or at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I cannot still understand my example - I am making x threads and always new instance, so i thought that boolean without volantile will be sufficient, but I do not understand why It is not... :(

Comment: You want the main thread to set the `cancelled` field to `true` and have that change be visible to the worker thread. Without `volatile` (or some other mechanism) that is not guaranteed to happen. The worker thread might just forever see the initial value of `false`.

Comment: Java can "optimize" your program (i.e., re-write it for efficiency.) To get the best efficiency, it is allowed to assume that variables are not shared by threads except in special cases. `volatile` is one such case: Java must assume that a `volatile` variable could be changed by any thread at any time. If you have non-volatile `boolean b;` and you have a loop, `while(b){...}`. The compiler can change that to `while(true)` if it can prove that the loop never sets `b=false`. But, if `b` is `volatile`, the system must assume that some other thread could set `b=false`.